# Ignoring withspaces and comments with regex pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on a Java program and I need help to create this pattern:

```
I\sam\s(.+)
```

I would like to ignore all the whitespaces after the first group, for example if the name is "George P             " it should be counted only the "George P".
Also I wanted to consider the comment character *, ignoring all the characters after this. If there's is no * and it's found many whitespaces the matcher should fail.

Comment: @LambdaNinja I want o consider what comes after "I am ", however, characters after the coment (*) whould be ignored. Like "I am George *W", the 'W' should be ignored, aswell as if the name finishes with whitespaces, like "I am George       " (has many whitespaces after George), should only be counted as "George" with no spaces.

Comment: At the momend i have this regex `(I\sam\s(\S+))|(I\sam\s.+(?:\*.+))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update2**
RE: `DC` regex, per comment.

`^\s*(DC\s)((\d+)(\.)?(\d+)?)(?=\s*(?:\*|$))`

```
 ^                             # BOS
 \s*                           # Optional whitespace's

 ( DC \s )                     # (1), DC + single whitespace
 (                             # (2 start)
      ( \d+ )                       # (3), 1 or more Digits
      ( \. )?                       # (4), Optional dot .
      ( \d+ )?                      # (5), Optional 0 or more Digits
 )                             # (2 end)

 (?=                           # Lookahead qualifier Assertion
      \s*                           # Optional whitespace's
      (?:                           # ---------------------
           \*                            # Asterisk (comment)
        |                              # or,
           $                             # End of string
      )                             # ---------------------
 )
```

---

**update**
The asterisk is *NOT* included in group 1:

`I\sam\s([^*]*)(?:(?<!\s)|(?<=I\sam\s))`

Explained

```
 I \s am \s                    # 'I am '

 ( [^*]* )                     # (1), Capture after that, but not asterisk or after

 (?:                           # Trimming
      (?<! \s )                     # Trim, no wsp behind
   |                              # or,
      (?<= I \s am \s )             # Just 'I am ' behind
 )
```

---

The asterisk *IS* included in group 1:

`I\sam\s([^*]*\*?)(?:(?<!\s)|(?<=I\sam\s))`

(*Note -Trimming conditions make this regex more complex. It's better to not trim within the regex, but use language api's to trim the contents of capture 1 after the match.*)

Explained

```
 I \s am \s                  # 'I am '

 ( [^*]* \*? )               # (1), Capture after that, but not after asterisk

 (?:                         # Trimming
      (?<! \s )                   # Trim, no wsp behind
   |                            # or,
      (?<= I \s am \s )           # Just 'I am ' behind
 )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, there's only a little problem, I'm already working on it. If i write "I am George *A", group 1 is returning "George *".

Comment: just perfect, works for all possible cases. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Imagine i have the following case:

'^\\s*(DC\\s)(((\\d+)(\\.)?(\\d+)?))(?:(?<!\\s)|(?<=DC\\s))'
Which mean it's possible to write, for example DC 1, DC 11 our DC 11.11.

In this case the '(?:(?<!\\s)|(?<=DC\\s))' part allow me write something like: DC 1TEXT, which shouldn't be allowed, only DC 1 * COMMENT (* is for comments) should.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @rJqnr - You can't conflate this _`DC`_ regex with the other ones. Added an update for this latest one.

Comment: Works just perfect :D Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

`"I\\sam\\s[a-zA-Z]+\\s+[a-zA-Z]+"`

Your problem might be, that you have to escape the escape character, as `\s` is `Pattern` special character. Not java's. This will match:

```
I am George P
I am Tom     D
I am sdawawe x
```

Won't match:

```
I am    George P
I   am Geor s
```

Is it what you wanted?